# How to define XML element in xsd schema to make all child elements to have same attribute value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

```
<root>
<elem type="1" id="1"/>
<elem type="1" id="2"/>
</root>
```

I want to check in XSD schema so that all the elements should have same attribute value for "type".
Suppose one element has type="1" and other element has type="2", Then I want schema validation to fail.
How to restrict this in Schema?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible in xsd 1.0.

I don't know what exactly are you dealing with but in this case it would give me a sense to have some wrapping element, e.g. `elems` which would hold that value. Thus

```
<root>
   <elems type="1">
      <elem id="1"/>
      <elem id="2"/>
   </elems>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single value for type, why not put that single value in one place, instead of replicating it in multiple places?  That is, why not structure your XML this way?

```
<root type="1">
  <elem id="1"/>
  <elem id="2"/>
</root>
```

The fact that the different elements aren't allowed to have distinct type values is prima facie evidence that type is not strictly speaking an attribute of elem, but a property of the document as a whole.

That way, the structure of the XML already guarantees that there is just one value for type, instead of allowing an inconsistency that you or the validator must then add an extra ad-hoc check for.

There may also be some more complicated ways to ensure that there is only one value for type (maybe something very clever with key and keyref constraints; in XSD 1.1, use of assertions; use of external or internal Schematron assertions), but I don't want to encourage their use when there is such a simple alternative.